# cannot reach port 80 from Windows to Docker image

Tags: docker

Running on Windows 10 with Docker Installed

```
// DockerFile
FROM ubuntu:latest
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y apache2
ADD index.html /var/www/html/
CMD /usr/sbin/apache2ctl -D FOREGROUND
EXPOSE 80
```

// building image, running container and checking IP

```
$ docker network inspect bridge
```

and getting [image]

```
"IPv4Address": "172.17.0.2/16"
```

when trying to access via Chrome browser to http://172.17.0.2, I get "This site can’t be reached"

Comment: On Windows 10 you should be able to reach your service via localhost. Important is also how you run the container (with port mappings)

Answer (score 0):

1. **Expose Port:** Please check have you exposed port number **80**. (not only in docker file)? but In your docker run command, you need to specify "**-p 80:80**". Can you please share your command, how you are running your docker container?
2. **IPAddress:** 172.17.0.2 This IPAddress is docker internal docker ip address, you need to use **localhost** or **your_machine_ip_address** to access that docker container.

Please let me know, If you have any difficulty with this, share your docker run command.